# Make a method return only when a transition is finished

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, transition, wait

I have a small question.
I have a method which has some Transitions inside it, with multiple Transitions I can use setOnFinished() to wait for another transition to finish, but my method will return immediately after it has been called.
How can I make my method wait for the last setOnFinished()?

```
greenBack.setOnFinished(e -> {
    //return the method
});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: The objective of a callback function to avoid waiting, if you want return value then you can either get the value from the callback parameters, otherwise some kind of setInterval function to monitor the changes of variables

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you are trying to do? You have "some transitions"? Are they running one after the other, or all at the same time, or what? Why not just register a listener with the last one to finish?

Comment: Some of the transitions were parallel others were sequential. I solved the problem by returning the last Transition and put a setOnFinished() at that return.